# Hw to Freeze the Button in Scroll bar

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using unity 2018.3.7. In my project  I have instantiate 25 buttons in the scroll bar..I am scrolling the button. It is working well.

Actually i want freeze the 12 the button.When i scroll the button. The 12 th button should be constantly should be there and other button should scroll go up.

scrolling should be done but the freeze  button should be constantly there.

Like Excel. If we freeze the top row. The top row is constantly there  and scrolling is happened.

Like that i have to do in unity.

How to Freeze the button  in scroll bar.

[image: Gif Imager]

Edit:

Actually I have uploaded new gif file. In that gif file 2 row is freezed (Row Heading1,Row Heading2, Row Heading3,RowHeading4).

2nd row is constantly there. Rest of the the rows 4 to 100 rows are going up.

Like that i have to do ...

How can i do it..

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand but couldn't you simply place it outside of the scrollbar/scrollrect?

Comment: @derHugo i have  posted the gif images. I have to freeze the particular  row and rest of the button constantly goes up..

Comment: as said ... why are you putting these within the scroll? simply but them outside of it and only scroll the rest ... that's kind of what happens in excel

Comment: 2nd row is an example only. Dynamically i have to freeze the columns..for eg i have to freeze 12 or 24 column . if i freeze 12 th column.12th column should be constantly there. rest of the columns should go up. In unity i cant place them outside because all button content  is child of the scroll view.

Comment: you can move them out and back in the scroll view though

Comment: i cant move them out. because the button is the instantiate in the parent.if i make the child out.It is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question still is very broad I guess I got now what you want. This will probably not be exactly the solution you want since your question is quite vague but it should give you a good idea and starting point for implementing it in the way you need it.

---

I can just assume Unity UI here is the setup I would use. Since it is quite complex I hope this image will help to understand

[image]

so what do we have here:

- `Canvas`

  - has the `RowController` script attached. Here reference the row prefab and adjust how many rows shall be added
- `Panel` is the only child of `Canvas`. I just used it as a wrapper for having a custom padding etc - it's optional
- FixedRowPanel

  - Here we will add the fixed rows on runtime
  - Initially has a height of **0**!
  - Uses anchore pivot **Y = 1**! This is later important for changing the height on runtime
  - Uses a `Vertical Layout Group` for automatically arranging added children
- `ScrollView` - Your scrollview as you had it **but**

  - Uses streched layout to fill the entire `Panel` (except later the reduced space for the fixed rows)
  - Uses anchor pivot **Y = 1**! Again important for changing the height and position on runtime later
- `Viewport` afaik it should already use streched anchors by default but not sure so make it
- `Content`

  - Uses a `Vertical Layout Group`
  - Initially has a height of **0** (but I set this in the code anyway) and will grow and shrink accordingly when adding and removing rows
- And finally `RowPrefab`

  - I didn't add its hierachy in detail but it should be clear. It has a Toggle and a Text as childs ;)
  - Has the `Row` script attached we use for storing and getting some infos

---

Now to the scripts - I tried to comment everything

The **Row.cs** is quite simple

```c#
public class Row : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference these via the Inspector
    public Toggle FixToggle;
    public Text FixTogText;
    public Text RowText;
    public RectTransform RectTransform;

    // Will be set by RowController when instantiating
    public int RowIndex;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!RectTransform) RectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        if (!FixToggle) FixToggle = GetComponentInChildren<Toggle>(true);
        if (!FixTogText) FixTogText = FixToggle.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);
    }
}
```

And here is the **RowController.cs**

```c#
public class RowController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Row RowPrefab;

    public RectTransform ScrollView;
    public RectTransform Content;
    public RectTransform FixedRowParent;

    public int HowManyRows = 24;

    public List<Row> CurrentlyFixedRows = new List<Row>();
    public List<Row> CurrentlyScrolledRows = new List<Row>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        // initially the content has height 0 since it has no children yet
        Content.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Content.sizeDelta.x, 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < HowManyRows; i++)
        {
            // Create new row instances and set their values
            var row = Instantiate(RowPrefab, Content);
            // store the according row index so we can later sort them on it
            row.RowIndex = i;
            row.RowText.text = $"Row Number {i + 1}";

            // add a callback for the Toggle
            row.FixToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(s => HandleToggleChanged(row, s));

            // increase the content's size to fit the children
            // if you are using any offset/padding between them 
            // you will have to add it here as well
            Content.sizeDelta += Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;

            // don't forget to add them to this list so we can easily access them
            CurrentlyScrolledRows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    // called every time a row is fixed or unfixed via the Toggle
    private void HandleToggleChanged(Row row, bool newState)
    {
        if (newState)
        {
            // SET FIXED

            // Update the button text
            row.FixTogText.text = "Unfix";
            // Move this row to the fixedRow panel
            row.transform.SetParent(FixedRowParent);

            // be default we assume we want the first position
            var targetIndex = 0;
            // if there are other fixed rows already find the first child of FixedRowParent that has a bigger value 
            if (CurrentlyFixedRows.Count > 0) targetIndex = CurrentlyFixedRows.FindIndex(r => r.RowIndex > row.RowIndex);
            // handle case when no elements are found -> -1
            // this means this row is the biggest and should be the last item
            if (targetIndex < 0) targetIndex = CurrentlyFixedRows.Count;

            // and finally in the hierachy move it to that position
            row.transform.SetSiblingIndex(targetIndex);

            // insert it to the fixed list and remove it from the scrolled list
            CurrentlyFixedRows.Insert(targetIndex, row);
            CurrentlyScrolledRows.Remove(row);

            // Make the fixed Panel bigger about the height of one row
            FixedRowParent.sizeDelta += Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;

            // Make both the scrollView and Content smaller about one row
            Content.sizeDelta -= Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;
            ScrollView.sizeDelta -= Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;
            // Move the scrollView down about one row in order to make space for the fixed panel
            ScrollView.anchoredPosition -= Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;
        }
        else
        {
            // SET UNFIXED - Basically the same but the other way round

            // Update the button text
            row.FixTogText.text = "Set Fixed";
            // Move this row back to the scrolled Content
            row.transform.SetParent(Content);

            // be default we assume we want the first position
            var targetIndex = 0;
            // if there are other scrolled rows already find the first child of Content that has a bigger value 
            if (CurrentlyScrolledRows.Count > 0) targetIndex = CurrentlyScrolledRows.FindIndex(r => r.RowIndex > row.RowIndex);
            // handle case when no elements are found -> -1
            // this means this row is the biggest and should be the last item
            if (targetIndex < 0) targetIndex = CurrentlyScrolledRows.Count;

            // and finally in the hierachy move it to that position
            row.transform.SetSiblingIndex(targetIndex);

            // insert it to the scrolled list 
            CurrentlyScrolledRows.Insert(targetIndex, row);
            // and remove it from the fixed List
            CurrentlyFixedRows.Remove(row);

            // shrink the fixed Panel about ne row height
            FixedRowParent.sizeDelta -= Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;

            // Increase both Content and Scrollview height by one row
            Content.sizeDelta += Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;
            ScrollView.sizeDelta += Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;
            // Move scrollView up about one row height to fill the empty space
            ScrollView.anchoredPosition += Vector2.up * row.RectTransform.rect.height;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Result:

[image]

As you can see I can now fix and unfix rows dynamically while keeping their correct order within both according panels.

Comment: How you make these gifs hugo?